# Splinter Is it possible to use browser.fill without name as a query

Tags: selenium, xpath, splinter

I would like to use an absolute xpath to fill in a search bar. The ids and classes are dynamically generated and there is no name variable or instance. So it feels like I'm stuck without a tool to fill in boxes without the named variable.

Is there a way around this? Can I somehow change the absolute xpath to look like its a name assignment and then query and fill based on the new 'type' I assigned the absolute xpath?

Is there a method for this in Selenium if not available in Splinter?

I've select by CSS and I'm finding this error 'selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated'

Edit:

```
<div class="type-ahead-input-container" role="search">
<div class="type-ahead-input-wrapper">
<div class="type-ahead-input">
<label class="visually-hidden" for="a11y-ember10393">
Search
</label>
<!---->
<input id="a11y-ember10393" class="ember-text-field ember-view" aria-
autocomplete="list" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" 
placeholder="Search" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" role="combobox" 
aria-expanded="true" aria-owns="ember11064" data-artdeco-is-focused="true"/>
<div class="type-ahead-input-icons">
<!---->
</div>
</div>
<!---->
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post a snippet of the HTML code.  Since it's dynamically assigned, post another snippet of the same section of HTML code.  Sometimes while the id might be dynamic it might be only partly dynamic, or there might be some other key.

Comment: Ok, I added it. I was wondering if they were allowing manipulation of the code by adding the visually hidden 'label'.

Answer (score 0):

As you have asked `Is there a method for this in Selenium`, the Answer is Yes.

Selenium supports Sikuli. Sikuli automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code.

You can find more about Sikuli [here](http://www.sikuli.org).

Let me know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you get an error-message like that, it could be that your search result is not what you expected. It could be that you are getting more than one result, ie a list. On a list you can not input.

You can find the input boxes with an xpath, select the prefered one from the list (by trying) and put a text in it with the WebDriverElement _set_value method. That is not appropriate because of the _, but it is usefull.

input_list = browser.find_by_xpath('//div[@class="type-ahead-input"]/input[@class="ember-textfield ember-view"]')

input_list[1]._set_value('just a text to see whether it is working')